# How can I install Faience GTK theme in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: apt, themes, gtk, software-installation

I have tried adding the PPA and installing through the terminal, but this did not work.

Is there any way I can get the most recent version of Faience GTK theme as a .deb file so it can be installed via the Software Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help but none of your solutions worked. I found out I can download the .deb package from https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox/+files/faience-theme_0.5.4_all.deb and then install it via software centre.

Answer (score 1):

The Faience theme PPA (https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox) is not officially updated for 13.10 (and hasn't had updates in 36 weeks as of writing). The latest supported release is 13.04.

The below steps will add the 13.04 (Raring) Faience PPA to your system. I assume it will work fine, though I can't test myself.

1. Execute these commands in a terminal to add the Raring PPA:

   ```bash
   sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu raring main'
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install the theme with some of the commands below:

   - Faience GTK / GNOME Shell theme (I believe this is the one you want)

     ```bash
     sudo apt-get install faience-theme
     ```
   - Faience icon theme:

     ```bash
     sudo apt-get install faience-icon-theme
     ```
   - Faenza icon theme:

     ```bash
     sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
     ```
3. Install one of these tools to change the theme to the Faience theme:

   - #### Unity Tweak Tool (My tool of choice)

     ```bash
     sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
     ```
   - #### Ubuntu Tweak

     Follow the instructions provided [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html), they should work in 13.10 as well.

Comment: I tried that it gave me "Error: need a single repository as argument" when I pasted "sudo add-apt-repository \
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu raring main"

Comment: @AlexLi See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu raring main 

sudo add-apt-repository \
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu raring main
```

Execute this instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
```

Comment: This wont work. The PPA lacks packages for 13.10; the PPA will be added successfully but no packages will be available. BTW, I said it was untested.